# need help with a locality

Tags: translation, japanese-to-english, kyūjitai-and-shinjitai

I know Musashi (武蔵) refers to the old province, but I cannot understand the rest of this sentence. Can anyone help with translation of 國小俳山? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In older times, 國 (modern 国) was the suffix for provinces, generally read as ～のくに.  [Japanese Wikipedia article for Musashi Province](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A6%E8%94%B5%E5%9B%BD), corresponding [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musashi_Province).

小佛山 is the older spelling for 小【こ】仏【ぼとけ】山【やま】 ("Little Buddha Mountain"), which appears to be an older or alternative name for 城山【しろやま】 ("Castle Mountain") in modern-day Kanagawa Prefecture.  [Japanese Wikipedia article for *Shiro-yama*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9F%8E%E5%B1%B1_(%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E9%83%BD%E3%83%BB%E7%A5%9E%E5%A5%88%E5%B7%9D%E7%9C%8C)), and there doesn't seem to be a corresponding article in English.  Also, [searching Google Maps for 小仏山](https://www.google.com/maps?q=%E5%B0%8F%E4%BB%8F%E5%B1%B1) shows results for this same 城山.

PS: Your text seems less like a sentence, and more like a label.

Comment: Thank you so much @Eiríkr Útlendi! Much appreciated. I would never have figure it out. And yes you are correct, it is indeed a label, not a sentence.